# Is SharePoint Framework able to be used to develop applications?

Tags: spfx

Recently I found out about SP Framework, I'm still not sure how powerful SP framework will be, is SP framework capable to be used to develop decent applications like leave management system (submission forms, approval workflow and forms)?

And is there any articles or links that listed down what SP framework can or cannot do?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned recently by Vesa Juvonen from Microsoft (source: https://www.spcaf.com/blog/sharepoint-framework-webinar-qa-follow-part-2-sharepoint-framework-capabilities/):

> The engineering team is investigating releasing additional shapes and parts as part of the SharePoint Framework. Stay tuned for updates.

If you're interested in learning more about what the SharePoint Framework can and cannot do, I suggest you read https://blog.mastykarz.nl/when-use-sharepoint-framework/.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the SharePoint Framework at some point will be able create advanced applications.

But the current (September 2016) developer preview is only for development of Client-Side WebParts.

In order to develop what you describe you'll probably need to combine it with a SharePoint AddIn. Such a combination has been hinted to be on the plan, but currently with no more information.